# How to include lua scripting language into C++ XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, lua, libraries

I have successfully compiled lua in my mac. It works. It runs. Now, I want to mix it with C++ in XCode. So I looked up in the Linked Library, the usual place to add more libraries in XCode. But of course, lua isn't there. Now, how do I tell XCode the existence of lua so that the program can include lua.h correctly?

Comment: If you haven't already, check out http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html - it may help you integrate your C++ and Lua code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Up to you :

- use the "Header Search Path" and "Library Search Paths" in the properties to add the location of Lua headers and liblua.a
- OR just copy the Lua headers and liblua.a in your project directory, then add them to your project

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/breinhart/Lua-In-Xcode